# Arrays with getters and setters not getting result

Tags: java, setter, getter

I am trying to get to work getters and setters with arrays, I have created 2 objects Question and Answer with their get and setters. I have also created 2 arrays one called Question and one called Answer.

```
 class Question {
    private String[] questions;

    public void setQuestion(String questions[]) {
        this.questions = questions;
    }

    public String[] getQuestion() {
        return questions;
    }
}

class Answer {
    private String[] answers;

    public void setAnswer(String answers[]) {
        this.answers = answers;
    }   

    public String[] getAnswer() {
        return answers;
    }
}
```

But when trying to print the questions it does not recognise `getQuestion'

```
for (int n = 0; n<getQuestion.length; n++) {
    System.out.println("Question" + (n+1));
    System.out.println(getQuestion(Question[n]);
}
```

Comment: you need an object of `Question` class to invoke non-static public functions

Answer (score 1):

`getQuestion` is a method of your Question class and should be called like that, like `questions.getQuestion()`. Probably, you want to return a single question for `getQuestion` too?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an instance of the `Question` class then call the `getQuestion()` method.

Depending on what you are trying to do you may also need to make the `Question` class public using the `public` modifier

**Note**
You could also as Pavneet_Singh pointed out make the `getQuestion()` method `static` thus removing the need to create a new instance of the `Question` class.

---

### Updated code

```
Question question = new Question();

for (int n = 0; n<question.getQuestion().length; n++) {
    System.out.println("Question" + (n+1));
    //note that this wont work, you dont pass any parameters to the getQuestion() method
    System.out.println(getQuestion(Question[n]);
}
```

---

Some improvements to your code;

```
public class Question {

   private String question;

   //Use Question constructor to populate the question string
   public Question( String question ){
      this.question = question;
   }

   //get the question
   public String getQuestion(){
     return question;
   }
}

//follow same pattern here
public class Answer {

   private String answer;

   public Answer( String answer ){
      this.answer = answer;
   }

   public String getAnswer(){
     return answer;
   }
}
```

**Main Method**

```
//Create array of type Question
Question[] questions = new Question[3];

//create new questions and use constructor to set string question
Question question1 = new Question('What is your name?');
Question question2 = new Question('What is your age?');
Question question3 = new Question('What is your favourite color?');

//add questions to array
questions.add(question1);
questions.add(question2);
questions.add(question3);
int counter = 0;

//loop through the array
for (Question question : questions) {
   System.out.println("Question " + (counter+1));
   System.out.println(question.getQuestion();
   counter++;
}
```

---

Ill let you figure out how to map questions to answers

Comment: @NicoHaase It wont as it stands. OP does not have an overloaded `getQuestion()` method in their `Question` class that accepts a `Question` parameter.